# CSS Grid rows in alignment but they create unnecessary white space below the entries

Tags: html, css

it's about the CSS for my digital edition of my doctoral thesis.

We have such a new LaTeX package that not only allows us to compile a nice pdf with a decent critical device, but it also spits out a TEI-based xml file at the same time. This is automatically converted into an .html file with an XSLT2 processor.

I have attached the html file and the CSS file.

It works well. However, I still have a tiny problem with the display of the html

I use a CSS grid (see style.css) with two columns and any number of rows to map the one .edition paragraph and one .translation paragraph in alignment in the .html file. That works too and is aligned. However, the height of the rows is always based on the highest paragraph in the superordinate . This creates a lot of white space in the rows of the grid. I would love to have this excess white space no longer there. But I just can't get it right and have already spent hours experimenting, and although I've come a long way with the help of others, I can't do this fine-tuning. Nevertheless, I am convinced that it should be possible somehow with CSS.

Do you have the brilliant idea?

I would be really grateful for help.

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: row dense;
  grid-gap: 0.5rem;
}

h1 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: none;
}

.edition,
.translation {
  display: inherit;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  row-gap: 10px
}

.edition {
  grid-column-start: 1;
}

.translation {
  grid-column-start: 2;
}

.edition>div[type="ed"] {
  background-color: #def;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}

.translation>div[type="trans"] {
  background-color: #abc;
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<h1>Tattvayogabindu</h1>

<div xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" xml:id="div-edition_1" class="edition">
  <div type="ed">
    <h3 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"></h3>
    <centerline>
      <textrm><small>[Introduction]</small></textrm>
    </centerline>
    <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="wapp">
      <p> <mark>śrī gaṇeśāya namaḥ</mark> // </p>
      <div class="app"><span class="lem">śrī gaṇeśāya namaḥ (<a href="#E" title="E Printed Edition">E</a> <a href="#L" title="L LALCHAND 5876">L</a> <a href="#N1" title="N1 NGMPP 38/31">N1</a> <a href="#D1" title="D1 IGNCA 30019">D1</a> <a href="#U1" title="U1 SORI 1574">U1</a> <a href="#U2" title="U2 SORI 6082">U2</a>) ]</span>        śrī ṇe ya maḥ (<a href="#P" title="P Pune BORI 664">P</a>), śrī gurave namaḥ (<a href="#N1" title="N1 NGMPP 38/31">N1</a>), śrī sarasvatyai namaḥ śrī nirañjanāya namaḥ (<a href="#D1" title="D1 IGNCA 30019">D1</a>), oṃ śrī niraṃjanāya (<a href="#U1"
          title="U1 SORI 1574">U1</a>)</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div type="ed">
    <h3 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"></h3>
    <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="wapp">
      <p> <mark>atha rājayogaprakāro likhyate</mark> // </p>
      <div class="app"><span class="lem">atha rājayogaprakāro likhyate (<a href="#N1" title="N1 NGMPP 38/31">N1</a> <a href="#D1" title="D1 IGNCA 30019">D1</a>) ]</span> atha rājayogaprakāra likhyate (<a href="#U1" title="U1 SORI 1574">U1</a>), rājayogāntargataḥ / binduyogaḥ
        (<a href="#E" title="E Printed Edition">E</a>), atha tattvabiṃduyogaprāraṃbhaḥ (<a href="#L" title="L LALCHAND 5876">L</a>), atha rājayoga liṣyate (<a href="#P" title="P Pune BORI 664">P</a>), atha rājayoga likhyate (<a href="#U2" title="U2 SORI 6082">U2</a>)</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div type="ed">
    <h3 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"></h3>
    <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="wapp">
      <p> rājayogasyedaṃ phalaṃ / yena rājayogenānekarājyabhogasamaya eva / anekapārthivavinoda<mark>prekṣaṇasamaya</mark> eva / bahutarakālaṃ śarīrasthitirbhavati / sa <mark>eva</mark> rājayogaḥ / tasyaite bhedāḥ / </p>
      <div class="app"><span class="lem">prekṣaṇasamaya (<a href="#P" title="P Pune BORI 664">P</a> <a href="#N1" title="N1 NGMPP 38/31">N1</a> <a href="#D1" title="D1 IGNCA 30019">D1</a> <a href="#U1" title="U1 SORI 1574">U1</a>) ]</span> prekṣyaṇasamaya (<a href="#U2"
          title="U2 SORI 6082">U2</a>)</div>
      <div class="app"><span class="lem">eva (<a href="#P" title="P Pune BORI 664">P</a> <a href="#N1" title="N1 NGMPP 38/31">N1</a> <a href="#D1" title="D1 IGNCA 30019">D1</a> <a href="#U2" title="U2 SORI 6082">U2</a>) ]</span> evaṃ (<a href="#U2" title="U2 SORI 6082">U2</a>)</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div type="ed">
    <h3 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"></h3>
    <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="row">
      <div class="column">
        <div class="wapp">
          <p>kriyāyogaḥ / jñānayogaḥ / <mark>cāryayogaḥ</mark> / haṭhayogaḥ / karmayogaḥ / <mark>layayogaḥ</mark> / dhyānayogaḥ / mantrayogaḥ / <mark>lakṣyayogaḥ</mark> / vāsanāyogaḥ / śivayogaḥ / brahmayogaḥ / advaitayogaḥ / <mark>siddhayogaḥ / rājayogaḥ</mark>            / <mark>ete pañcadaśayogāḥ</mark> //</p>
          <div class="app"><span class="lem">cāryayogaḥ (<a href="#P" title="P Pune BORI 664">P</a> <a href="#N1" title="N1 NGMPP 38/31">N1</a> <a href="#D1" title="D1 IGNCA 30019">D1</a> <a href="#U2" title="U2 SORI 6082">U2</a>) ]</span> tvaryāyogaḥ (<a href="#U1" title="U1 SORI 1574">U1</a>)</div>
          <div class="app"><span class="lem">layayogaḥ (<a href="#P" title="P Pune BORI 664">P</a> <a href="#N1" title="N1 NGMPP 38/31">N1</a> <a href="#D1" title="D1 IGNCA 30019">D1</a> <a href="#U1" title="U1 SORI 1574">U1</a>) ]</span> nayayogaḥ (<a href="#U2" title="U2 SORI 6082">U2</a>)</div>
          <div class="app"><span class="lem">lakṣyayogaḥ (<a href="#P" title="P Pune BORI 664">P</a> <a href="#N1" title="N1 NGMPP 38/31">N1</a> <a href="#D1" title="D1 IGNCA 30019">D1</a> <a href="#U2" title="U2 SORI 6082">U2</a>) ]</span> lakṣayogaḥ (<a href="#U1" title="U1 SORI 1574">U1</a>)</div>
          <div class="app"><span class="lem">siddhayogaḥ / rājayogaḥ (<a href="#P" title="P Pune BORI 664">P</a> <a href="#U2" title="U2 SORI 6082">U2</a>) ]</span> rājayogaḥ / siddhayogaḥ (<a href="#N1" title="N1 NGMPP 38/31">N1</a> <a href="#D1" title="D1 IGNCA 30019">D1</a>            <a href="#U1" title="U1 SORI 1574">U1</a>)</div>
          <div class="app"><span class="lem">ete pañcadaśayogāḥ (<a href="#P" title="P Pune BORI 664">P</a> <a href="#N1" title="N1 NGMPP 38/31">N1</a> <a href="#D1" title="D1 IGNCA 30019">D1</a> <a href="#U1" title="U1 SORI 1574">U1</a>) ]</span> evaṃ paṃcadaśāyogā bhavaṃti
            (<a href="#U2" title="U2 SORI 6082">U2</a>)</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <p class="analysis">The initial codification of 15 yogas appears in N1,P,D1,U1 and U2. It is ommitted in E and L. B can't be determined due to missing folios. P is the only witness which numbers the yogas with devanāgarī-digits. The other witnesses separate the list
          with single or double daṇḍas.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" xml:id="div-translation_1" class="translation">
  <div type="trans">
    <h3 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"></h3>
    <centerline>
      <textrm><small>[Introduction]</small></textrm>
    </centerline>
    <p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">Homage to Śrī Gaṇeśa.</p>
  </div>
  <div type="trans">
    <h3 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"></h3>
    <p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> Now the methods of rājayoga are laid down. </p>
  </div>
  <div type="trans">
    <h3 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"></h3>
    <p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">This is the result of <span class="italic">rājayoga</span><span class="note">This statement seems unconnected to the definition of rājayoga that follows.</span>: <span class="italic">Rājayoga</span> is that by which longterm durability of the body
      arises even amongst manifold royal pleasures even amongst the manifold royal entertainments and spectacle. This truly is <span class="italic">rājayoga</span>. Of this [<span class="italic">rājayoga</span>] these are the varieties: </p>
  </div>
  <div type="trans">
    <h3 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"></h3>
    <p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">1. Yoga of [mental] action (<span class="italic">kriyāyoga</span>), 2. Yoga of knowledge (<span class="italic">jñānayoga</span>), 3. Yoga of wandering (<span class="italic">caryāyoga</span>), 4. Yoga of force (<span class="italic">haṭhayoga</span>),
      5. Yoga of deeds (<span class="italic">karmayoga</span>), 6. Yoga of absorption (<span class="italic">layayoga</span>), 7. Yoga of meditation (<span class="italic">dhyānayoga</span>), 8. Yoga of mantras (<span class="italic">mantrayoga</span>),
      9. Yoga of fixation objects (<span class="italic">lakṣyayoga</span>), 10. Yoga of mental residues (<span class="italic">vāsanāyoga</span>), 11. Yoga of Śiva (<span class="italic">śivayoga</span>), 12. Yoga of Brahman (<span class="italic">brahmayoga</span>),
      13. Yoga of non-duality (<span class="italic">advaitayoga</span>), 14. Yoga of completion (<span class="italic">siddhayoga</span>) 15. Yoga of kings (<span class="italic">rājayoga</span>). These are the fifteen <span class="italic">yoga</span>s.
      <span
        class="note">At the current stage of research it is not clear if this list is a later addition by another scribe or, if indeed it originally stems from Rāmacandra. The list suggests a text following the order of yogas according to this list. However, the order
        and even the designation of some of the yogas given in the list is just followed very loosely in the text.</span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" xml:id="div-edition_2" class="edition">
  <div type="ed">
    <h3 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"></h3>
    <centerline>
      <textrm><small>[Description of <span xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="italic">kriyāyoga</span>]</small></textrm>
    </centerline>
    <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="wapp">
      <p><mark>idānīṃ</mark> <mark>kriyāyogasya</mark> lakṣaṇaṃ <mark>kathyate</mark>/</p>
      <div class="app"><span class="lem">idānīṃ (<a href="#P" title="P Pune BORI 664">P</a> <a href="#N1" title="N1 NGMPP 38/31">N1</a> <a href="#D1" title="D1 IGNCA 30019">D1</a> <a href="#U1" title="U1 SORI 1574">U1</a>) ]</span> atha (<a href="#U2" title="U2 SORI 6082">U2</a>)</div>
      <div class="app"><span class="lem">kriyāyogasya (<a href="#P" title="P Pune BORI 664">P</a> <a href="#N1" title="N1 NGMPP 38/31">N1</a> <a href="#D1" title="D1 IGNCA 30019">D1</a> <a href="#U1" title="U1 SORI 1574">U1</a>) ]</span> kriyāyogas (<a href="#U2" title="U2 SORI 6082">U2</a>)</div>
      <div class="app"><span class="lem">kathyate (<a href="#P" title="P Pune BORI 664">P</a> <a href="#N1" title="N1 NGMPP 38/31">N1</a> <a href="#U1" title="U1 SORI 1574">U1</a>) ]</span> kathayate (<a href="#D1" title="D1 IGNCA 30019">D1</a>), \om (<a href="#U2" title="U2 SORI 6082">U2</a>)</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div type="ed">
    <h3 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"></h3>
    <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="wapp">
      <p>
        <tl xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">kriyāmuktirayaṃ yogaḥ svapiṇḍe <mark xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">siddhidāyakaḥ</mark>/</tl>
        <tl xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">yaṃ yaṃ karoti kallolaṃ kāryāraṃbhe manaḥ sadā/</tl>
        <tl xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"><mark xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">tattataḥ</mark> kuñcanaṃ kurvankriyāyoga<mark xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">stato bhavet</mark>//1//</tl>
      </p>
      <div class="app"><span class="lem">siddhidāyakaḥ (<a href="#P" title="P Pune BORI 664">P</a> <a href="#N1" title="N1 NGMPP 38/31">N1</a> <a href="#D1" title="D1 IGNCA 30019">D1</a> <a href="#U1" title="U1 SORI 1574">U1</a>) ]</span> siddhidāyakaṃ (<a href="#U2"
          title="U2 SORI 6082">U2</a>)</div>
      <div class="app"><span class="lem">tattataḥ (<a href="#P" title="P Pune BORI 664">P</a> <a href="#N1" title="N1 NGMPP 38/31">N1</a> <a href="#D1" title="D1 IGNCA 30019">D1</a>) ]</span> tatastataḥ (<a href="#U2" title="U2 SORI 6082">U2</a>), taṃkṛ taṃ (<a href="#U1"
          title="U1 SORI 1574">U1</a>)</div>
      <div class="app"><span class="lem">stato bhavet (<a href="#P" title="P Pune BORI 664">P</a> <a href="#U2" title="U2 SORI 6082">U2</a>) ]</span> ato bhava (<a href="#N1" title="N1 NGMPP 38/31">N1</a> <a href="#D1" title="D1 IGNCA 30019">D1</a>), ato va (<a href="#U1"
          title="U1 SORI 1574">U1</a>)</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div type="ed">
    <h3 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"></h3>
    <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="row">
      <div class="column">
        <div class="wapp">
          <p>
            <tl xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">kṣamā<mark xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">viveka</mark>vairāgyaṃ śāntisantoṣa<mark xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">nispṛhāḥ</mark>/</tl>
            <tl xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">eta<mark xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">dyuktiyuto</mark> <mark xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">yogī</mark> kriyāyogī nigadyate//2//</tl>
          </p>
          <div class="app"><span class="lem">viveka (<a href="#N1" title="N1 NGMPP 38/31">N1</a> <a href="#D1" title="D1 IGNCA 30019">D1</a> <a href="#P" title="P Pune BORI 664">P</a> <a href="#U1" title="U1 SORI 1574">U1</a>) ]</span> vivekaṃ (<a href="#E" title="E Printed Edition">E</a>            <a href="#U2" title="U2 SORI 6082">U2</a>)</div>
          <div class="app"><span class="lem">nispṛhāḥ (<a href="#P" title="P Pune BORI 664">P</a>) ]</span> °niṣpṛhāḥ (<a href="#U2" title="U2 SORI 6082">U2</a>), °nispṛhā (<a href="#E" title="E Printed Edition">E</a> <a href="#N1" title="N1 NGMPP 38/31">N1</a>), °nispṛhaḥ
            (<a href="#D1" title="D1 IGNCA 30019">D1</a>), °niṣpṛhī (<a href="#U1" title="U1 SORI 1574">U1</a>)</div>
          <div class="app"><span class="lem">dyuktiyuto (<a href="#E" title="E Printed Edition">E</a> <a href="#P" title="P Pune BORI 664">P</a> <a href="#N1" title="N1 NGMPP 38/31">N1</a> <a href="#D1" title="D1 IGNCA 30019">D1</a> <a href="#U1" title="U1 SORI 1574">U1</a>) ]</span>            muktiyuto (<a href="#U2" title="U2 SORI 6082">U2</a>)</div>
          <div class="app"><span class="lem">yogī (<a href="#E" title="E Printed Edition">E</a> <a href="#P" title="P Pune BORI 664">P</a> <a href="#N1" title="N1 NGMPP 38/31">N1</a> <a href="#D1" title="D1 IGNCA 30019">D1</a> <a href="#U2" title="U2 SORI 6082">U2</a>) ]</span>            yosau (<a href="#U1" title="U1 SORI 1574">U1</a>)</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <p class="analysis">E starts here.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div type="ed">
    <h3 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"></h3>
    <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="wapp">
      <p>
        <tl xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"><mark xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">mātsaryaṃ</mark> mamatā māyā <mark xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">hiṃsāśā</mark> madagarvatā/</tl>
        <tl xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">kāma<mark xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">krodhau</mark> bhayaṃ lajjā lobhamohau tathā <mark xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">'śuciḥ</mark>//3//</tl>
      </p>
      <div class="app"><span class="lem">mātsaryaṃ (<a href="#E" title="E Printed Edition">E</a> <a href="#U1" title="U1 SORI 1574">U1</a> <a href="#U2" title="U2 SORI 6082">U2</a>) ]</span> mātsarya (<a href="#P" title="P Pune BORI 664">P</a> <a href="#N1" title="N1 NGMPP 38/31">N1</a>        <a href="#D1" title="D1 IGNCA 30019">D1</a>)</div>
      <div class="app"><span class="lem">hiṃsāśā (<a href="#P" title="P Pune BORI 664">P</a> <a href="#D1" title="D1 IGNCA 30019">D1</a> <a href="#U1" title="U1 SORI 1574">U1</a> <a href="#U2" title="U2 SORI 6082">U2</a>) ]</span> hiṃsā ca (<a href="#E" title="E Printed Edition">E</a>),
        hiṃsāḥ (<a href="#N1" title="N1 NGMPP 38/31">N1</a>)</div>
      <div class="app"><span class="lem">krodhau (<a href="#U1" title="U1 SORI 1574">U1</a> <a href="#U2" title="U2 SORI 6082">U2</a>) ]</span> krodha° (<a href="#E" title="E Printed Edition">E</a> <a href="#P" title="P Pune BORI 664">P</a> <a href="#N1" title="N1 NGMPP 38/31">N1</a>),
        °krodho (<a href="#D1" title="D1 IGNCA 30019">D1</a>)</div>
      <div class="app"><span class="lem">'śuciḥ (<a href="#P" title="P Pune BORI 664">P</a> <a href="#N1" title="N1 NGMPP 38/31">N1</a> <a href="#D1" title="D1 IGNCA 30019">D1</a> <a href="#U1" title="U1 SORI 1574">U1</a>) ]</span> śuciḥ (<a href="#E" title="E Printed Edition">E</a>        <a href="#U2" title="U2 SORI 6082">U2</a>)</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div type="ed">
    <h3 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"></h3>
    <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="row">
      <div class="column">
        <div class="wapp">
          <p>
            <tl xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"><mark xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">rāgadveṣau</mark>ghṛṇālasyaṃ <mark xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">bhraṃtirdaṃbho</mark> <mark xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">kṣamā bhramaḥ</mark>/</tl>
            <tl xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">yasyaitāni <mark xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">na</mark>vidyante kriyāyogī sa ucyate//4//</tl>
          </p>
          <div class="app"><span class="lem">rāgadveṣau (<a href="#E" title="E Printed Edition">E</a> <a href="#P" title="P Pune BORI 664">P</a> <a href="#N1" title="N1 NGMPP 38/31">N1</a> <a href="#D1" title="D1 IGNCA 30019">D1</a> <a href="#U2" title="U2 SORI 6082">U2</a>) ]</span>            rāgadoṣau (<a href="#U1" title="U1 SORI 1574">U1</a>), athadveṣo (<a href="#L" title="L LALCHAND 5876">L</a>)</div>
          <div class="app"><span class="lem">bhraṃtirdaṃbho (<a href="#P" title="P Pune BORI 664">P</a> <a href="#L" title="L LALCHAND 5876">L</a> <a href="#N1" title="N1 NGMPP 38/31">N1</a> <a href="#U2" title="U2 SORI 6082">U2</a>) ]</span> bhrāṃtir debho (<a href="#D1"
              title="D1 IGNCA 30019">D1</a>), bhrāntitvaṃ (<a href="#E" title="E Printed Edition">E</a>), bhrāṃti daṃbha (<a href="#U1" title="U1 SORI 1574">U1</a>)</div>
          <div class="app"><span class="lem">kṣamā bhramaḥ (<a href="#L" title="L LALCHAND 5876">L</a> <a href="#N1" title="N1 NGMPP 38/31">N1</a> <a href="#D1" title="D1 IGNCA 30019">D1</a> <a href="#U2" title="U2 SORI 6082">U2</a>) ]</span> mokṣamābhramaḥ (<a href="#E"
              title="E Printed Edition">E</a>), °kṣamī bhramaḥ (<a href="#U1" title="U1 SORI 1574">U1</a>)</div>
          <div class="app"><span class="lem">na (<a href="#P" title="P Pune BORI 664">P</a> <a href="#L" title="L LALCHAND 5876">L</a> <a href="#N1" title="N1 NGMPP 38/31">N1</a> <a href="#D1" title="D1 IGNCA 30019">D1</a> <a href="#U1" title="U1 SORI 1574">U1</a> <a href="#U2" title="U2 SORI 6082">U2</a>) ]</span>            ca (<a href="#E" title="E Printed Edition">E</a>)</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <p class="analysis">L starts here.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div type="ed">
    <h3 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"></h3>
    <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="wapp">
      <p> yasyāntaḥkaraṇe <mark>kṣamā</mark>vivekavairāgyaśānti<mark>santoṣa ityādīny</mark> <mark>utpādyante</mark> / </p>
      <div class="app"><span class="lem">kṣamā (<a href="#E" title="E Printed Edition">E</a> <a href="#P" title="P Pune BORI 664">P</a> <a href="#L" title="L LALCHAND 5876">L</a> <a href="#D1" title="D1 IGNCA 30019">D1</a> <a href="#U1" title="U1 SORI 1574">U1</a> <a href="#U2" title="U2 SORI 6082">U2</a>) ]</span>        kṣamāḥ (<a href="#N1" title="N1 NGMPP 38/31">N1</a>)</div>
      <div class="app"><span class="lem">santoṣa ityādīny (<a href="#P" title="P Pune BORI 664">P</a> <a href="#N1" title="N1 NGMPP 38/31">N1</a> <a href="#D1" title="D1 IGNCA 30019">D1</a>) ]</span> santoṣādīny (<a href="#E" title="E Printed Edition">E</a>), ityādīno°
        (<a href="#L" title="L LALCHAND 5876">L</a>), ityādīna niraṃtaram (<a href="#U1" title="U1 SORI 1574">U1</a>), ityādayoniraṃtaraṃ (<a href="#U2" title="U2 SORI 6082">U2</a>)</div>
      <div class="app"><span class="lem">utpādyante (<a href="#P" title="P Pune BORI 664">P</a> <a href="#N1" title="N1 NGMPP 38/31">N1</a> <a href="#D1" title="D1 IGNCA 30019">D1</a> <a href="#U2" title="U2 SORI 6082">U2</a>) ]</span> utpadyante (<a href="#E" title="E Printed Edition">E</a>),
        utyaṃte (<a href="#U1" title="U1 SORI 1574">U1</a>)</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div type="ed">
    <h3 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"></h3>
    <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="wapp">
      <p> sa eva <mark>bahukriyāyogī</mark> <mark>kathyate</mark> /</p>
      <div class="app"><span class="lem">bahukriyāyogī (<a href="#E" title="E Printed Edition">E</a> <a href="#P" title="P Pune BORI 664">P</a> <a href="#L" title="L LALCHAND 5876">L</a> <a href="#N1" title="N1 NGMPP 38/31">N1</a> <a href="#U1" title="U1 SORI 1574">U1</a> <a href="#U2" title="U2 SORI 6082">U2</a>) ]</span>        bahukriyāyogā (<a href="#D1" title="D1 IGNCA 30019">D1</a>)</div>
      <div class="app"><span class="lem">kathyate (<a href="#E" title="E Printed Edition">E</a> <a href="#P" title="P Pune BORI 664">P</a> <a href="#L" title="L LALCHAND 5876">L</a> <a href="#N1" title="N1 NGMPP 38/31">N1</a> <a href="#U1" title="U1 SORI 1574">U1</a>) ]</span>        sa kathyate (<a href="#D1" title="D1 IGNCA 30019">D1</a>), tkacyate (<a href="#U2" title="U2 SORI 6082">U2</a>)</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" xml:id="div-translation_2" class="translation">
  <div type="trans">
    <h3 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"></h3>
    <centerline>
      <textrm><small>[Description of <span xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="italic">kriyāyoga</span>]</small></textrm>
    </centerline>
    <p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">Now the characteristic of the Yoga of [mental] action (<span class="italic">kriyāyoga</span>) described. </p>
  </div>
  <div type="trans">
    <h3 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"></h3>
    <p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><span class="bold">1.</span> This Yoga is liberation through [mental] action. It bestows success(<span class="italic">siddhi</span>) in ones own body. Each wave the mind creates at the beginning of an action, of all those one shall withdraw oneself.
      Then <span class="italic">kriyāyoga</span> arises. </p>
  </div>
  <div type="trans">
    <h3 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"></h3>
    <p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><span class="bold">2.</span> Patience, discrimination, equanimity, peace, modesty, desireless: The <span class="italic">yogī</span> who is endowed with these means is said to be a <span class="italic">kriyāyogī</span>. </p>
  </div>
  <div type="trans">
    <h3 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"></h3>
    <p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><span class="bold">3.</span> Envy, selfishness, cheating, violence, desire and intoxication, pride, lust, anger, fear, laziness, greed, error and impurity. </p>
  </div>
  <div type="trans">
    <h3 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"></h3>
    <p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><span class="bold">4.</span> Attachment and aversion, indignation and idleness, impatience and dizzyness: Whoever does not possess these is called a <span class="italic">kriyāyogī</span>. </p>
  </div>
  <div type="trans">
    <h3 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"></h3>
    <p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">[] Patience, discrimination, equanimity, peace, contentment etc. are generated in his mind. </p>
  </div>
  <div type="trans">
    <h3 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"></h3>
    <p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">[] He alone is called a <span class="italic">yogī</span> of many actions (<span class="italic">bahukriyāyogī</span>). </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you talking about these white spaces? - https://ibb.co/0CT2SPp

Comment: those I want to keep. I mean the space below text and edition

Comment: https://ibb.co/f8kBrYT